# How to pass value inside href to laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel

This is code snippet from my view file.

```
@foreach($infolist as $info)
 <a href="">{{$info->prisw}} / {{$info->secsw}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Here is my route which I defined inside route file

```
Route::get('switchinfo','SwitchinfoController');
```

I want to pass two values inside href tag to above route and retrieve them in controller. Can someone provide code to do this thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you are trying to pass two parameters to your controller,

You controller could look like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class SwitchinfoController extends Controller{

    public function switchInfo($prisw, $secsw){
       //do stuffs here with $prisw and $secsw
    }
}
```

Your router could look like this

```
$router->get('/switchinfo/{prisw}/{secsw}',[
    'uses' => 'SwitchinfoController@switchInfo',
    'as'   => 'switch'
]);
```

Then in your Blade

```
@foreach($infolist as $info)
  <a href="{!! route('switch', ['prisw'=>$info->prisw, 'secsw'=>$info->secsw]) !!}">Link</a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 5):

Name your route:

```
Route::get('switchinfo/{parameter}', [
     'as'=> 'test',
     'uses'=>'SwitchinfoController@function'
]);
```

Pass an array with the parameters you want

```
 <a href="{{route('test', ['parameter' => 1])}}">
    {{$info->prisw}} / {{$info->secsw}}
 </a>
```

and in controller function use

```
function ($parameter) {
   // do stuff
}
```

Or if don't want to bind parameter to url and want just `$_GET` parameter like `url/?parameter=1`

You may use it like this

```
Route::get('switchinfo', [
    'as'=> 'test', 
    'uses'=>'SwitchinfoController@function'
]);

function (){
     Input::get('parameter');
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-route)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply pass parameter in your url like

```
@foreach($infolist as $info)
<a href="{{ url('switchinfo/'.$info->prisw.'/'.$info->secsw.'/') }}">
{{$info->prisw}} / {{$info->secsw}}
</a>
@endforeach
```

and route

```
Route::get('switchinfo/{prisw}/{secsw}', 'SwitchinfoController@functionname');
```

and function in controller

```
public functionname($prisw, $secsw){
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: how to retrieve those two parameters from the controller #Rehan?

Comment: In controller, functionname in above code $prisw and $secsw are your values, you can use them to access parameter values

Comment: it will be visible in browser's address field that is insecure